# How can i access Page.FormViewDetails.DataKey?

Tags: asp.net, forms, datalist, datakey

I need to get the selected item from DataList in ASPNET in a general logging procedure not knowing the control name or datakey name (can be different from page to page). The only place I can find this data seems to in Page.FormViewDetails.DataKey?

I tried the following:

```
System.Web.UI.Page page = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Handler as System.Web.UI.Page;
var _barVariable = typeof(System.Web.UI.Page).GetField("FormViewDetails", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(page);
```

Bit this gives an object reference not set exception, I can see the content of Page.FormViewDetails in watch and VS debugger:
[VS debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6zHG.png)

Why Am I getting null reference exception?
Is there an easier way to access this info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo strProperty = page.GetType().GetProperty("FormViewDetails", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
System.Reflection.MethodInfo strGetter = strProperty.GetGetMethod(nonPublic: true);

FormView val = (FormView)strGetter.Invoke(page, null);
```